# jQuery class w/ certain NOT value selector

Tags: jquery, serialization, selector

I am trying to select only items of class `.hidden-line-id` which are HTML `inputs`, but I don't want any that have no value.

I tried this:

```
var serialized = $(checkeditems).parents("tr").find(".hidden-line-id[value!='']").serialize();
```

but I am still getting empty AJAX params in the serialized string.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the attribute equal (or not equal) selectors only looks at attributes, not properties. I'm assuming you wanted access to the property since the attribute only contains the default value of the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[value!='']` only selects elements with an empty **HTML `value` attribute**. If you want to test for the *current* value of the input, you can use [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
$(checkeditems).parents("tr").find(".hidden-line-id").filter(function() {
    return this.value !== '';
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that did exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to consider the *current* value of an input, and not just what was set in the HTML attribute, you need to `.filter()` based on the element's `value`:

```
var serialized = $(checkeditems).parents("tr")
                     .find(".hidden-line-id")
                     .filter(function() {
                         return this.value.length; // or $(this).val().length
                     })
                     .serialize();
```